# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Deployment Quandry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk with an environment setup (Windows Server 2012, IIS 8, Load Balanced).  When I first create the environment with a .NET application, everything appears to work just fine.  However, when I redeploy the application - using the AWS tools for Visual Studio 2012 - the new version does not seem to be deployed. I see the new deployment bundle up inthe proper S3 location, and the event viewer in the console indicates that everything is going fine:

```
Environment update is starting.
Deploying new version to instance(s).
Command execution completed successfully.
New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
Environment update completed successfully.
```

However, no new files appear on the server. Just for a check, I deleted all of the files in the **c:\inetpub\wwwroot** directory (the application deploys as the root app) and when the redeploy completes, I still do not see any files in this directory. I've tried to snapshot the logs, but there don't appear to be any (the list comes back empty).  I've checked the deployments log files on the server itself (via RDP) and they are also empty. I've checked the server's event viewer as well - also void of any messages. It is almost as if the server is not actually running the deployment.

I am not sure what I could be doing wrong, but any guidance or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I was using a custom AMI for the beanstalks. I found out that the AMI I was using was not beanstalk-friendly, even though I created it from a beanstalk EC2 instance that I had customized. There was something in the configuration that made the new machines not deploy properly. In any case, for now I decided that I should just update my deployment package to include the stuff I needed (e.g., C++ redistributable) as opposed to trying to customize the machine images (i.e., [Command for Elastic Beanstalk configuration to install Visual C++ Redistributable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264537/command-for-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-to-install-visual-c-redistributabl/23085509#23085509)).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked under your 'Application Versions'?

[image]

It is possible that the bundle has been uploaded but not running on the instances.